# Issue with threejs and shaders showing an sphere glow

Tags: three.js, shader

I am working on a 3d visualization. I need to show a world with its atmosphere and I based on an example that was with threejs r40 but mine is r71.

When I try to add the atmosphere (kind of a glow to the sphere that represents the world) I am getting the following error:

`three.min.js:445 Uncaught TypeError: c.addEventListener is not a function`

My code is the following:

```
scene.add(createAtmosphere());

function createAtmosphere() {

    shader = Shaders['atmosphere'];
    uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(shader.uniforms);
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.Sphere(200, 40, 30), 
        new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

          uniforms: uniforms,
          vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
          fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader

        })
      );

    mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 1.1;
    mesh.flipSided = true;
    mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    mesh.updateMatrix();
    return mesh;
  }
```

and this is the shader

```
var Shaders = {
    'atmosphere' : {
      uniforms: {},
      vertexShader: [
        'varying vec3 vNormal;',
        'void main() {',
          'vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );',
          'gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );',
        '}'
      ].join('\n'),
      fragmentShader: [
        'varying vec3 vNormal;',
        'void main() {',
          'float intensity = pow( 0.8 - dot( vNormal, vec3( 0, 0, 1.0 ) ), 12.0 );',
          'gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ) * intensity;',
        '}'
      ].join('\n')
    }
  };
```

I solved another shader issue but I cant find what is wrong in this one (I am not familiar with shaders and it driving me crazy).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your mesh sending a `SphereGeometry`, not a `Sphere`.

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/Mesh
http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/SphereGeometry

```
scene.add(createAtmosphere());

function createAtmosphere() {

    shader = Shaders['atmosphere'];
    uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(shader.uniforms);
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(200, 40, 30), 
        new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

          uniforms: uniforms,
          vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
          fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader

        })
      );

    mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 1.1;
    mesh.flipSided = true;
    mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    mesh.updateMatrix();
    return mesh;
  }
```

Comment: Yes you are right, in fact I change this when showing the earth (long day yesterday). Anyway, using SphereGeometry doesn't show anything (https://gist.github.com/glena/0b2875044cd6c39ff150). I should go back to D3 and stick to 2D hahaha

Comment: @GermánLena Do you still get the error your mentioned? If not it might be a problem with your shader. Try to first create the mesh with a normal material and see if it gets displayed. You might also want to mark this one as answered and create a new question, since it's a different problem.

Comment: You are right, I posted a new question here, do you have any clue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538512/issue-upgrading-threejs-with-shaders