# Issue upgrading threejs with shaders

Tags: three.js, shader

I am working on a 3d dataviz. I need to show a world with data on it and I using the chrome experiments (chromeexperiments.com/globe) as a guide.

The issue is that this visualizations are made with Threejs r40 and it is hard to find docs about it so I tried to upgrade to r71.

I solved the compatibility issues rendering the world but cant make it show the atmosphere, in fact, when I try to show the atmosphere nothing is shown (is like the atmosphere is rendered black and it hides the world).

I think that the problem is the shader but I am not really sure.

Does anybody have a clue?

This is the code I am using:

gist.github.com/glena/0b2875044cd6c39ff150

Thanks

==========

Update:

if I remove the fragentShader, this is rendered as a red sphere but stills covers the world with a black background:

```
 var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 40, 30), 
        new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

          uniforms: uniforms,
          vertexShader: shader.vertexShader

        })
      );
```

Comment: Any way you could make this a working jsfiddle?

Comment: Try `mesh.flipSided = true;` ==> `mesh.material.side = THREE.BackSide;`

Comment: Yes, but it is not loading the image for the world, it is throwing CORS errors so I change for a simpler one without shaders and a solid color https://jsfiddle.net/sfuc3wf2/

Comment: @WestLangley Wow this was the issue and seems to be working. Thanks!. Thanks

Comment: @WestLangley hey man, answer the question and I will delete my answer if you want.

Comment: @WestLangley I understand the mathematics, I got lost with the BC breaks between R40 and R71.

Comment: That's OK. You can accept your own question or delete the post.

Answer (score 0):

The issue (as said by @WestLangley) was

```
mesh.flipSided = true; ==> mesh.material.side = THREE.BackSide;
```